# zabbix-server.service: PID file /var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

Tags: pid, zabbix

First of all, I would like to say that I know there are already posts on this subject here, but none of them had any useful answer, so this is why I'm doing another post.

So I installed Zabbix on a Ubuntu machine, and every time I try to run zabbix-server, I get this error:

```
 zabbix-server.service: PID file /var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure why, since the rights seems good and the file is there, and config seems good too.
Please let me know if you have an idea, or if more information are needed.

Thanks

Edit: Zabbix 3.4 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you mention the version of Zabbix server you have installed along with the version of Ubuntu you have used??

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Sure thing! Just edited my post with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an error message neither a bug. The Zabbix support team decided not to fix it. 
My guess for the message is -> Whenever the zabbix server is stopped, the file /var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid is deleted as that PID number is killed. When you start the service next time Zabbix checks the pid file to make sure it is NOT there like a zombi process.
The Zabbix validate startup telling "PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory" 
This means it is OK to write the new pid file.
check their resolution: Won't fix.
This message is still alive in Zabbix 4.0.3
https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-14788?jql=text%20~%20%22pid%20not%20readable%22